# Convert List<DTO?> to List<DTO>

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want convert List<DTO?> to List

```
List<DTO?> items = new List<DTO?>();

List<DTO> notNullItems = items.Where(c=>c!=null).ToList();
```

But it does not work!

Doesn't match target type

Comment: `items.Where(c=>c!=null).Select(d=>(DTO)d).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Select` the `Value` property because the type might not be matched when you only use `Where` the type still be `DTO?` nullable type.

```
List<DTO> notNullItems = items.Where(c=>c!=null)
                              .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

As @Jeroen Mostert commented if your type isn't nullable `Cast` might be more suitable.

```
List<DTO> notNullItems = items.Where(c=>c!=null)
                              .Cast<DTO>.ToList();
```

Comment: That only works if `DTO` is a `Nullable` of some sort, not if it's a nullable reference type (which seems a lot more likely for a type named `DTO`). `.Cast<DTO>()` is universal.

Comment: i have not *.Value* property !!!!!

Comment: @JeroenMostert .Cast<DTO>() worked

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) (`!`).

If you add `!` after the `.ToList()`, you'll the C# compiler that you know it's not null:

```cs
List<DTO> notNullItems = items.Where(c => c != null).ToList()!;
```

This will have better performance than `.Cast<DTO>()` since it doesn't call a method. But we're probably talking nanoseconds here.

Note that this only works with classes. If you're using [Nullable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types), then you'll have to use `.Select(c => c.Value)`.